# how to clone and create a new database in RDS MySql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to create a new database with the contents of the existing database.
It's like cloning the existing database and making a new one.
This is for a switchover purpose.

How to do it in RDS MySQL?

Comment: Use MySQL Workbench to export the current schema and data, to create the new database.

Comment: I am looking for some RDS based solutions rather than going to database and importing things..I need an exact clone of existing ones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to clone an RDS instance is to create a snapshot of your instance (or use an existing snapshot) then restore that snapshot into a new instance.

For more information visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html

When you restore the DB instance, you provide the name of the DB snapshot to restore from, and then provide a name for the new DB instance that is created from the restore. You cannot restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a new DB instance is created when you restore.